# CFRelease causes crash

Tags: c++, macos

The following bit of code causes a crash in my C++ application:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef property_dictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable( kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks );

if ( ! property_dictionary )
  break;

CFDictionarySetValue( property_dictionary, CFSTR( "somekey" ), CFSTR("someval") );
CFMutableDictionaryRef match_dictionary = CFDictionaryCreateMutable( kCFAllocatorDefault, 0,
                    &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks );

if ( ! match_dictionary )
  break;

CFDictionarySetValue( match_dictionary, CFSTR(kIOPropertyMatchKey), property_dictionary );

io_iterator_t service = IOServiceGetMatchingService( kIOMasterPortDefault, match_dictionary );

if ( property_dictionary != NULL )
  CFRelease( property_dictionary );

// the following bit causes crash
if ( match_dictionary != NULL )
  CFRelease( match_dictionary );
```

I wonder if IOServiceGetMatchingService has anything to do with it.

Comment: Does the crash go away if you remove the call to `IOServiceGetMatchingService`?

Comment: Yes it does, as it turns out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IOServiceGetMatchingService()` is peculiar in terms of memory management. It consumes one reference to the passed-in dictionary. Since your code only had a single reference, it no longer owns the `match_dictionary` dictionary after the call and must not call `CFRelease()` on it.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOKitLib_header_reference/#//apple_ref/c/func/IOServiceGetMatchingService):

> *`matching`* A CF dictionary containing matching information, of which one reference is always consumed by this function…

Comment: Brilliant! Ken, you're a legend. Don't know why but I totally missed that statement when reading through the docs.

Comment: @ken could you please have a look at my below issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873319/cfrelease-crash-in-ios10?noredirect=1#comment67038350_39873319